# How to parse Json arrays of objects in React JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs, object

**Can someone help me to print out the required data on the web by parsing JSON array of objects? In the below example, I want to print Apple, Mango, Grapes.**

Below are the codes:

JSON format

```
{
    "data":{
        "summary": {
        'a1':13223,
        'b1': 23
        },
        "regional": [
            {
                'aa1': "Apple",
                'bb1': 456
            },
            {
                'aa1': "Mango",
                'bb1': 496
            },
            {
                'aa1': "Grapes",
                'bb1': 126
            },
        ]
    },
    'lastdata': '2946'
}
```

fetchApi.js

```
url = 'apiUrl'
export const fetchData = async () => {
    try {
    const { data } = await (await fetch(url)).json();
    const modifiedData = {
            region: [...data.regional]
        }
        return modifiedData;
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
}
```

tabular.js

```
import { fetchData } from "../api/fetchApi";
const Tabular = () => {
    const [fetchedState, setFetchedState] = useState([])
    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchAPIState = async () => {
            const dailyData = await fetchData()
            setFetchedState(dailyData)
            console.log(dailyData) 
        }
        fetchAPIState()
    }, [])

     return (
        <>
        <h1>{}</h1>
        </>
            )
}
```

When I console.log(dailyData)
the result is this:

```
"region": [
            {
                'aa1': "Apple",
                'bb1': 456
            },
            {
                'aa1': "Mango",
                'bb1': 496
            },
            {
                'aa1': "Grapes",
                'bb1': 126
            },
        ]
```

But I am unable to print Apple, Mango, Grapes in the h1 tag.
It shows error.
I tried using map method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fetchApi.js, make

```
modifiedData = [...data.regional];
```

Or, in tabular.js, you need to use `map` on `fetchedState.region`

In the jsx part(assuming you did the latter), if you give the same key to all the fruit names, and bb1 is a unique id, replace the `<h1>{}</h1>` with:

```
{fetchedState.region.map(e => <h1 key={e.bb1}>{e.aa1}</h1>)}
```

Comment: Please don't use the array index as `key`. There are performance issues on using array-index as key. You can go through this beautiful piece of article by Ken C Dodds and understand the React `key` prop more well - https://kentcdodds.com/blog/understanding-reacts-key-prop

Answer (score 1):

So, from your question what I understand that you want to render a list of elements from your `dailyData` array, right? If that's the case then we can do that by using javascript `map()` on the `fetchedState` (because you're saving `dailyData` array to that state) and generate the list of elements. Finally, we can render that list of elements in the `JSX` side. Or, you can directly do the transforming i.e. `map()` part in the `JSX` side.

But the `dailyData` array of objects you gave has not a consistent shape. For creating an element for each *Apple*, *Mango*, *Grapes* in the `h1` tag you must have a data/array where these values are in the same `key/property`; here I can see Apple, Mango, Grapes have 3 different `key` i.e. `aa1`, `cc1`, `ee1`!! So, are you sure that the data points you are showing are correct?

Comment: Json data has been edited. I found the answer to the question.